# Power Dissipation - Sizing up Power Supply Needed

Tags: power-supply, current, integrated-circuit, power-dissipation

I wanted to understand what size power supply is needed for the following: I am getting confused with the Icc value and Ioh,Iol etc values in the datasheet. My question is, how much current will I need to supply to U1 device assuming the values I have here. Even though Icc=500uA is in the datasheet as max, won't the IOH value add to this number? I am assuming frequency is low and input capacitance is low for this example.

[image]

Comment: What are U1 and U2, how much they use power internally, and what kind of impedances they have? Now it looks like you have copied input leakage current and output drive strength so these don't show the actual current flowing in the circuit.

Comment: As long as ioh of the driving IC is more than the iih of the receiver, the link will work. To see how much current to add to Iq, you use the iih, not the ioh, as it's only the iih that gets drawn.

Comment: Icc= current with no load so you are correct to add load to base current.

Comment: @Neil_UK. Doesn't  the Ioh come from U1 in this case? Wouldn't it be part of Icc of U1?

Comment: The quiescent Icc usually assumes all outputs unloaded, so any Ioh is in addition to the quoted Icc.